# Excel Sumif for consolidating product weights

Tags: excel

This is a very specific query for a project-
I have: Aisles(with product locations)/Products/location weights:

```
Aisleslocation ProductId Weight(Kg) ConsolidateFlag
B2  3   600 N
B3  3   100 Y
B4  3   90  Y
B5  3   70  Y
A5  2   200 N
A6  2   200 N
A4  2   200 N
B1  2   99  Y
A1  2   100 Y
A2  1   200 N
C2  1   200 N
A3  1   100 Y
C3  1   100 Y
C5  1   90  Y
C1  1   30  Y
C4  1   20  Y
```

I would like to know a way in Excel to execute a consolidate flag for the the weights of products (flag Y for products that can be moved to other locations in an aisle without exceeding the product max weight). 
Max weight will be either 500 or the max weight of the product in stock.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in cell D2. It's an array formula, so use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to commit. Then copy down.

```
=IF(OR(MAX(IF(B:B=B2,C:C,0))=C2,2>500),"N","Y")
```

Comment: Hi Marco, thank you for the response - it doesnt seem to work - I have got close with an aisle helper column next to Location column and the formula:=IF(AND(COUNTIFS(C:C,C2,B:B,LEFT(A2,1))>1,SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,B2,C:C,C2)<VLOOKUP(C2,C:D,2,FALSE)),"Y","N") -- but of course the SUMIF also SUMs the max weight products of an aisle too so doesnt flag the smaller values in that aisle

Comment: I don't understand what you want then. Can you explain the criteria a  bit more?

Comment: I also did not use the right columns (edited my answer). The output in the D-column is exactly the same as in your example.

Comment: Hi Marco, I think you have edited and provided the correct answer for my needs, upvoted. Are you able to provide a link to a resource to help me be less ignorant with this query or explain the logic behind your code? Thank you very much

Comment: Before I explain my answer, can you confirm that I used the correct criteria? The result of the formula is N when the value in column C is bigger then 500 or the value in column C is the maximumweight for that particular productID. So I did not do anything with column A. Is this correct?